# What is the smallest number of socks you should pull out so that you can be assured that you will have at least one pair of matching socks?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Anyone can help me with this math problem?

Your drawer has 
5 pairs of black socks, 
4 pairs of gray socks, 
2 pairs of white socks, 
1 pair of brown socks, and 
1 pair of blue socks. 
The lights are out, and you're in a rush to leave. 
What is the smallest number of socks you should pull out 
so that you can be assured that 
you will have at least one pair of matching socks? 
Note that there are no left or right socks 
and two socks of the same color will be considered matching.

Comment: Hint: pigeon hole principle.

Answer (score 4):

Well, what is the biggest number of socks you can pull out so that you have no match (If you are really unlucky)?

After finding that number, you will just have to add $1$.

Note that this is a riddle that is well known, you will find many hints on the internet if you really search.