# Probability of getting a matching pair of socks

Tags: probability-distributions

A drawer contains 3 black socks, 4 red socks and 6 white socks. What is the probability that there is a matching pair of socks if three socks are taken from the drawer at random?

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried?

Comment: I thought we should divide 25 by 286 but it's incorrect

Comment: Hint: try finding the complement, that there are _no_ matching socks among the three chosen. Then subtract that probability from $1$ to get your answer.

Comment: Possible dublicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1915191/what-is-the-smallest-number-of-socks-you-should-pull-out-so-that-you-can-be-assu

Comment: I think the correct answer is 137/143 but I'm not sure. Could you check if it's correct or not?

Comment: The correct answer is $107/143$.   See demarco's solution.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this is by calculating the probability of the complement and subtracting the answer from one.  To calculate the probability directly would require you to count all the ways of getting *at least* 2 of one color.  There are $\binom{13}{3}$ ways of choosing the socks and $6 \cdot 4 \cdot 3$ ways of getting a combination of three unique colors.  So the answer is $$
1-\frac{6 \cdot 4 \cdot 3}{\binom{13}{3}}
$$